# Estimate time needed for command to run using pv

Tags: linux, bash

I'm processing some text files with my custom python script. To track progress I'm using pv command. Right now I'm parsing only several MB of data, but would like to know how much time would it take to process several GB. The command that I used was

```
python command | pv -l -s 2g
```

This gave me output

```
1,56M 0:03:06 [8,38k/s] [>                                    ]  0%
```

I know that I can calculate time based on these parameters but I want automate this process.

After reading through manual I found -e option that gives ETA for given size

```
python command | pv -l -e -s 2g
```

Now I can see ETA being displayed when command is running, but there is a lot of other logs from the script that cover this message. Is there any way to display estimated time(or save last given ETA) when the script ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
python command | pv -l -e -s 2g -f 2>pv.log
tr '\r' '\n' <pv.log | grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' | tail -n1
```

Explanations:

- You can dump the `pv` printouts into a file by redirecting fd 2 (stderr) to that file. You also need to force `pv` to produce output (with `-f`), as normally it only produces output when it detects that stderr is a terminal.
- If you dump printouts this way, the file will contain *all* printouts, not just the last.
- The printouts will be delimited by the "return" character `\r`, which instructs the terminal to move the cursor to the start of the line without switching to the next line, so the next printout overwrites the previous one. The `tr` command turns "returns" `\r` into regular "newlines" `\n`.
- To see the original contents of `pv.log`, try `cat -A pv.log`. (`cat` will display `\r` as `^M`.)
- The `grep` removes any lines containing only white space (spaces or tabs), as these might appear after the last printouts.
- The `tail` extracts the last printout.